# how to declare map interface in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a web frontend developer used javascript and typescript only before. And I'm trying to declare the interface for map.

It throw an error tell me that this can not be assigned to parameter type.

```dart
abstract class MockData {
  String id;
  String image;
}
// throw an error 
const List<MockData> mockData = [
  {
    'id': '001',
    'image': 'http://placehold.it/45x45?text=test',
  },
  ...
]
```

And what I expect is like the following in typescript.

```js
interface MockData {
  id: string;
  image: string;
}
const mockData: MockData[]  = [
  {
    'id': '001',
    'image': 'http://placehold.it/45x45?text=test',
  },
  ...
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `map` you need to have a `key` and `value`, example:

```
  const Map<String,String> mockData = 
  {
    'id': '001',
    'image': 'http://placehold.it/45x45?text=test',
  };
```

If you want to use the custom class, you can do the following:

```
 class MockData{
  String  id;
  String image;

   MockData(String name, String age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.image = image;
  }
}
```

Then create a `list` of type `MockData` and create an instance of the class:

```
  List<MockData> listOfData = List();
  var newDat                = MockData("1","001");
  listofData.add(newDat);
```